# Seeding Database Setting Max Length

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Im trying to seed my database with Faker.net because I need a lot of data generated, is it possible to set the phone numbers to only create 11 numbers long?

```
var addresses = Builder<deliveryAddress>.CreateListOfSize(40)
                .All()
            .With(c => c.FirstName = Faker.Name.First())
            .With(c => c.LastName = Faker.Name.Last())
            .With(c => c.Address = Faker.Address.StreetAddress())
            .With(c => c.City = Faker.Address.City())
            .With(c => c.Country = Faker.Address.UkCountry())
            .With(c => c.PostalCode = Faker.Address.UkPostCode())
            .With(c => c.Mobile = Faker.Phone.Number().)
            .With(c => c.Phone = Faker.Phone.Number())
                .Build();

            context.deliveryAddresses.AddOrUpdate(c => c.AdressId, addresses.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on `Faker.NET` source code, `Faker.Phone.Number()` can take a parameter. You can pass the pattern string like `"###-####-#####"` as a parameter to `Faker.Phone.Number(string pattern)`.

Saw your question on the phone, haven't got chance to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use String format to limit your string Characters.

Ex. String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", 9912345678);

```
This will output "(991) 234-5678".
```

Or also you can try:

const int MaxLength = 11;
var name = "1234567910123456";

if (name.Length > MaxLength)

```
name = name.Substring(0, MaxLength); // name = "12345678910"
```

or Refer this [trik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030353/convert-int-into-string-with-certain-length-of-char).

Comment: so how would I edit what code i've shown to do that? faker.phone.number()? @Jaimesh

Comment: int length = 11;        With(c => c.Mobile = Faker.Phone.Number.PadLeft(length, '0'));   Not exactly,But try this.

Comment: Wasn't solved, have tried all methods however to fix just changed my validation in class